# ¿Como puedo insertar de forma correcta con jquery codigo html junto a php en un modal?

Tags: php, jquery, modal

quiero insertar dentro de un modal un textfield con un boton que recoja el valor de este textfield al hacer click en el botón, para esto estoy usando jquery y estoy insertando el html junto a un `if(isset($_POST["boton"]))` en php para realizar una acción cuando se apriete el botón.
de esta forma:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#ModifCo').click(function(){
     $('#inyeccion').html('<form method="post">'+
                     '<table>'+
                     '<tr>'+
                        '<td>Comision de la AFP &nbsp</td>'+
                     '<td><input type="number" name="txtComisionAFP"></td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<td><br><input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton" value="Insertar Datos" class=" btn btn-default"> <br> </td>'+
                     '</form>'+
                     '<?php'+
                        'if(isset($_POST["boton"]))'+ 
                        '$ComisionAFP= $_POST["txtComisionAFP"];'+
                        'require_once "AFP.php";'+
                        'require_once "UpdateDB.php";'+
                        '$afp= new AFP("","","",$ComisionAFP);'+
                        '$op= new Update();'+
                        '$op->UpdateComision($afp);'+ 
                     '</table>')
});
```

El problema me surge acá `$op->UpdateComision($afp);` ya que jquery no detecta la flechita -> y me la manda solo como texto.

Bueno alguna sugerencia.
PD: estoy aprendiendo

Comment: PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, no en el navegador. Debes cambiar el enfoque.

Comment: Tienes que ver que es lo que quieres hacer amigo porque no hay necesidad de usar php cuando ya estas del lado del cliente y recuerda que **PHP** se ejecuta en el servidor y **javascript** del lado del cliente cualquier petición o cambio del DOM tienes que manejarlo con **javascript** cada lenguaje tiene su uso.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado, `PHP` se ejecuta del lado del servidor y `jquery` del lado del cliente, por lo que la respuesta rápida a tu pregunta es que no se puede.

Con lo que ahora mi consejo, o como lo haría yo.

En la página donde tengas la modal, deberías crear el código `Jquery`, que haga lo de recoger el valor del `textfield`, y de alguna manera te lanze un formulario para poder usar la parte que tienes de `if(isset($_POST["boton"]))`.

Se que la respuesta es un poco teórica, pero con el código que has puesto, es lo que te puedo comentar